# confused with the float behavior

Tags: css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>float</title>
    <style>
    .container {
        margin:0 auto;
        width:310px;
        height:500px;
        border:1px solid blue
    }

    .f {
        float:left;border: 1px solid red;width:100px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="f" style="height:100px">
        A
    </div>
    <div class="f" style="height:150px">
        B
    </div>
    <div class="f" style="height:200px">
        C
    </div>
    <div class="f" style="height:50px">
        D
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

1.open the html above with the broswer,it will look like this
[image]

2.decrease the C's height to 120px

now it will look like this
[image]

according to the specification:

> If the current box is left-floating, and there are any left-floating boxes generated by elements earlier in the source document, then for each such earlier box, either the left outer edge of the current box must be to the right of the right outer edge of the earlier box, or its top must be lower than the bottom of the earlier box. Analogous rules hold for right-floating boxes.

D's top must be lower than the bottom of the earlier box(A,B,C)
but now D's top is higher than B. why?

Comment: There is no images showing, also can you describe what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its say's either one of the two will be true.

> either the left outer edge of the current box must be to the right  of
>   the right outer edge of the earlier box,

OR

> or its top must be lower than the bottom of the earlier box.

For `D` Condition 1 is true with respect to `B` and Condition 2 is true with respect to `C`

Answer (score 0):

change the `conatiner width` to accomodate the `box D` if you need all the boxes to float in one line

```
 .container {
        margin:0 auto;
        width:410px;
        height:500px;
        border:1px solid blue
    }

    .f {
        float:left;border: 1px solid red;width:100px;
    }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cL396/)